# ¿Por qué este trigger no actualiza?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Para empezar mostrare la estructura de mis 3 tablas

```
este tabla seria los productos
Producto (
  CODIGO int(11),
  CANTIDAD int(11)
)
```

esta seria cabecera pedido

```
Pedido (
  codigo int(11),
  nombre varchar(50),
  unix varchar(100)
)
```

y esta seria la tabla detalle de pedido

```
Detalle (
  codigo int(11),
  producto int(11),
  cantidad` int(11)
)
```

en fin al registrar un pedido ,registra la cabecera y el detalle lo realiza bien

mi problema es que al borrar un pedido necesito que la cantidad de los productos registrados en el detalle pedido sean regresaron a la tabla Producto , hice un trigger que en teoria realizaria eso pero supongo que e fallado en el codigo porque borro una Pedido y no actualiza la tabla producto

```
CREATE TRIGGER Devolver_Productos_Prueba AFTER DELETE ON Detalle FOR EACH ROW

Update Producto
set Producto.CANTIDAD = (Producto.CANTIDAD + old.cantidad)
where Producto.CODIGO = old.codigo;
```

quisiera que me ayuden , gracias de antemano por su ayuda

Comment: Si pudieras redactar mas clara tu duda te lo agradecería pues no termino de entender tu duda

Comment: mi duda es porque el trigger que describi arriba no actualiza la tabla producto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la tabla **detalle** veo que pones los campos **codigo**, **producto**, y cantidad, lo que me da a entender que el campo **codigo** es la llave primaria de la tabla detalle probablemente.Ahora observa el trigger en esta parte: where Producto.CODIGO = ***old.codigo;*** no deberia ser  old.producto ? es decir deberias ponerlo asi:
where Producto.CODIGO = ***old.producto;***

Comment: Es un genio profe, no me habia dado cuenta de eso

Answer (score 3):

Debes recordar que el trigger se esta ejecutando por cada fila de la tabla `Detalle` que se elimina, por lo tanto `OLD` hace referencia al registro de la table `Detalle` que se esta eliminando

En el update que muestras hay un `old.cant` que es incorrecto basado en la tabla `Detalle`, lo correcto seria `OLD.cantidad`

Lo mismo con `old.cod`, lo correcto seria `OLD.codigo`

```
Update Producto
set Producto.CANTIDAD = (Producto.CANTIDAD + old.cantidad)
where Producto.CODIGO = old.codigo;
```

Y este seria el resultado final

Comment: Si gracias por esa observación, arregle el trigger pero sigue sin actualizar la tabla producto